# Rails google-oauth not working after POST request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, routes

I am using Google OAuth2 gem: https://github.com/zquestz/omniauth-google-oauth2 in rails, but after POST request is sent to Google API, nothing is happening.
[image]

In the log, I can see the message that POST request is sent, but nothing happens after seeing that message. I also checked API endpoint to check the traffic, but seems like no request is received.
[image]

In my routes.rb, I have a line defines `get 'auth/:provider/callback', to: 'sessions#omniauth'`,
and the link of a button is defined as `<%= button_to "Log in with Google", '/auth/google_oauth2' %>`.

I tried adding bunch of URLs in case I am not adding the correct one, but it seems like none of them works.
[image]

I feel like I am missing something very trivial but been stuck for a while. Does anyone have any idea why this is not working?

Comment: Are you using it with devise or standalone?

Comment: No I am not using neither of those. I believe we can still do it without them @rmlockerd?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using devise and the issue is resolved. I am still unsure why I could not set this up without using devise, but using devise was easy solution: https://github.com/heartcombo/devise

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).